# UIWebview Crash on Copy the content and remove the webview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, crash

I had a strange issue that, I load a pdf in UIWebview after loading, I copy the content using default webview copy.

And After some times I go back from the view after releasing the webview instance at that time the app got crashed.

See the log,

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "copy the content using default webview copy."?  Do you mean you are trying to copy the object instance using copyWithZone?

Comment: @RobReuss No, I try to ping copy the content in to UIPasteBoard. Its default in UIWebview. enable by a long press.

Comment: I see, so you're doing this copy operation as a user, while the app is executing?  My guess is that the resources you copied to the pasteboard are holding a reference to the UIWebView.  Make sure you eliminate any lingering references there.

Comment: @steipete No I try to do normal pinch copy in UIWebview.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your UIWebView is shutdown properly before being deallocated. Most importantly remove the delegate.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if ([self.webView isLoading]) {
        [self.webView stopLoading];
    }
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    if ([self.webView isLoading]) {
        [self.webView stopLoading];
    }
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
}
```

Comment: I already did the above code in viewDidUnload and in a function that I call to pop the controller. No Hope!